# Prove that: if $\frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{BC}{CF}$ then $AB\|DC\|EF$

Tags: geometry, triangles

Prove that: if $\frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{BC}{CF}$, then $AB\|DC\|EF$

[image: two muppets]

Comment: That didn't go well, did it? Please do try again, perhaps this time after reading the easy directions to post questions here.

Comment: What are $A,B,C,D,E,F$? Are they just some random points?

Comment: @DonAntonio ,@Wojowu.link fig http://math.irancircle.com/?qa=blob&qa_blobid=1106449990309608229

Comment: It can't be proved, because it's not true. Try looking for a counterexample instead, that will be much easier.

Comment: @elham.mj Good luck proving this fact.

Comment: @Futurologist.So, this statement is wrong?

Comment: What are those funny symbols separating AB from DC from EF, and what do they mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson AB,DC,EF :straight line , AD ,BC,DE,CF :the segment

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help. What does AB[funny symbol]DC mean? What does that funny symbol mean?

Comment: @elham.mj You did not format that part of the question in MathJax. It is possible that the symbol ∥ that you used will not display correctly for some people. Write `$AB\|CD$` instead in order to display $AB\|CD$.

Comment: The above is just a form of "inverse" Thales Theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio .Is there proof?

Comment: @elham.mj With the given data I'm not even sure it is true as written. Perhaps later I'll give a deeper thought as now I've got to go.

Comment: @elham.mj No, this is not true. You need something more. Some additional conditions. For instance, I can take any quadrilateral $ABFE$ with $AB$ not parallel to $EF$ and choose  $D$ and $C$ to be the midpoints of $AE$ and $BF$ respectively. Then your premise is true $$\frac{AD}{DE}=\frac{BC}{CF}=1$$ but the conclusion is not.